# Convert Excel Formula to DAX Which Averages Last 2 Values Until Certain Period of Time

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table in Excel:

```
DATE        VALUE
01/01/2024  100
02/01/2024  150
03/01/2024  200
04/01/2024  
05/01/2024  
06/01/2024  
07/01/2024  
08/01/2024  
09/01/2024  
10/01/2024  
11/01/2024  
12/01/2024
```

Lets say this table is called Table1. For the Months 4/1/2024 - 12/1/2024, I want to average the previous two month values. For Example: 4/1/2024 would be 175 (200 + 150), and 5/1/2024 would be 187.5 (200 + 175). I created this function to solve the Excel formula:

```
=REDUCE(FILTER(Table1[VALUE],Table1[VALUE]<>""),FILTER(Table1[VALUE],Table1[VALUE]=""),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,AVERAGE(TAKE(a,-2)))))
```

If I wanted to achieve this in Power BI DAX, how could I solve the problem?

Comment: Also posted here: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/convert-excel-formula-to-dax-which-averages-last-2-values-until-certain-period-of-time.1255611/